# Error 0xC0011008 the package failed to load

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, windows-server-2012, sql-agent-job, ssis-2014

I'm facing a strange behavior of `SQL Server Agent` when executing `SSIS` packages.

I have a job that includes many steps (mainly SSIS packages). Some steps fail mostly every day even the configuration is the same for all the steps.

I tried to delete/create the job, delete/create the `SQL Server Agent Proxy` but with no sucess.

I can't find any difference between the steps that fail and the ones that succeed.

This is the error returned by SQL Server Agent :

> The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information

SQL Server version : 2014

SSIS version : 2014

**EDIT :**

In the Event Log I found an `Information Message` from `User Profile Service` that says :

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards
>
> Process 5924 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX\Control Panel\International
>
> Process 5924 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

The `SID` corresponds to the `Proxy User` used to execute the SQL Job steps. And the timestamp corresponds is the same when the error occures in SQL Agent.

I think this is what causes the steps to fail.

Could we prevent Windows unloading this registry ?

Comment: How are you trying to execute the packages, as you're using SQL Server 2014 I *assume* you're making use of SSISDB?

Comment: The packages are stored in `MSDB` and I'm using `DTEXEC` to execute it.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using SSISDB? I believe the problem you're having wouldn't exist then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was indeed caused by the fact that the `User Profile Service` forces the unloading of the Registry.

The solution that worked for me was to change the policy setting `Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff` from "*Not Configured*" to **Enabled**.

1. Start the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
2. Go to *Computer Configuration* > *Administrative Templates* > *System* > *User Profiles*
3. Set "*Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff*" to Enabled
4. Run `gpupdate` command.

Details can be found here : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2287297/a-com-application-may-stop-working-on-windows-server-2008-when-a-user